# get value of inputbox in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get and alert content of `input textbox` but it doesn't work correctly can anybody help me?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var phoneField = $("#PhoneField").val();
  $("#SendPhone").click(function() {
    alert(phoneField);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
  <h2 class="fs-title">Enter Your Number</h2>
  <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
  <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Phone number" id="PhoneField" />
  <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" id="SendPhone" />
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Why you want to get value when page load?

Comment: Move the `var phoneField...` line into your click handler.

Answer (score 6):

You are assigning the `phoneField` variable only once, when the document is ready, that means that your `phoneField` will always be empty. Assign the variable in click event function and it should work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#SendPhone").click(function () {
    var phoneField = $("#PhoneField").val();
    alert(phoneField);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
  <h2 class="fs-title">Enter Your Number</h2>
  <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
  <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Phone number" id="PhoneField" />
  <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" id="SendPhone" />
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign variable after click event function and it should work.
Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#SendPhone").click(function () {
    var phoneField = $("#PhoneField").val();
    alert(phoneField);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you set the var phoneField on `pageload`, at pageload the input field is empty.

You can easily fix this by updating the var inside your onclick event.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var phoneField = $("#PhoneField").val();
  $("#SendPhone").click(function () {
    phoneField = $("#PhoneField").val(); //updates the variable
    alert(phoneField);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="fs-title">Enter Your Number</h2>
<h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Phone number" id="PhoneField" />
<input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" id="SendPhone" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You you want to get value on click event, then you should get value inside click event.

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
        
        $("#SendPhone").click(function () {
            var phoneField = $("#PhoneField").val();
            alert(phoneField);
        })
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
<h2 class="fs-title">Enter Your Number</h2>
<h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Phone number" id="PhoneField" />
<input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" id="SendPhone" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Take the value of text field when button is clicked. Currently it is initialised once when page is loaded.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#SendPhone").click(function () {
    alert($("#PhoneField").val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="PhoneField">
<input type="submit" id="SendPhone" value="Send">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<fieldset>
<h2 class="fs-title">Enter Your Number</h2>
<h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Phone number" id="PhoneField" />
<input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" id="SendPhone" />
</fieldset>


$(document).ready(function() {
  //var phoneField = $("#PhoneField").val();
  $("#SendPhone").click(function() {
    var phoneField = $("#PhoneField").val();
    alert(phoneField);
  });
});
```

You should get the value when `click` event excute.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="" value="" id="PhoneField" />
<input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" id="SendPhone" />

<script type="text/javascript">`$("#SendPhone").click(function() {
        var a = $("#PhoneField").val()
        alert(a)
    })`

</script>
```